# Can anyone identify this component? (possibly counter)

Tags: components, lcd, identification

I recently acquired this device, and I have no idea what it does, or how it works (or how to make it work). The guy who I got the device from told me that it was some kind of counter, but he could not tell me much more. Trying to figgure this one out has taken me the better part of the day, and I need some help please.

The device displays two small diamonds on the lcd display when you rub the middle contact. It also clicks when you shake it. The contacts look like some kind of rubber or fabric with embedded metal. The device is encased in plexiglass, and does not appear that it is open-able. The writing on the device is:

- 056 (in white screen print on bottom left)
- MB0956 REV X (Possibly
- MBO956, on bottom right)
- hy (appears to be a logo, on middle right)
- 9440 (under hy)
- hy-212 (under 9440)

Pictures of the device are shown below.

[image: front view 2 diamonds]
[image: back view]
[image: front view]
[image: contact]

Comment: That there would be a LCD with a circuit board.

Comment: The fact that you see things on the LCD when you rub the zebra-strips almost definitely tells you is has no integrated controller, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to guess from the pictures you've posted, but it looks like a simple LCD module.
Here's what I can tell from the desciption:

- The rubber contacts are called "zebra strips"
- The number "9440" probably means "week 40 of year 1994".

To make use of this display, you'd have to figure out the connections and make a PCB to to fit the zebra strip precisely. If I were you, I wouldn't bother trying to make use of this thing and would instead crack it open and see if there is anything interesting inside (hint: there probably isn't).

Comment: But then why does it may an odd clicking sound when shaken? (similar to blinkers on a car)

Comment: @reid, it is damaged?

Comment: @Reid Like I said, it *looks* like a simple module, but it may have some extra stuff between the PCB and the LCD. Impossible to tell from the pictures.

Comment: You are correct, it is just a simple LCD... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a ESL (Electronic Shelf Label), used in various shops/malls. Shows prices for some item, and gets its info through radio ou wi-fi of some sort...
Major player in this area is french SES-ESL, but this ain't of of them's...